# IntelliJ auto-rebuild is not working when any change comes

Tags: intellij-idea

I work with spring boot project with kotlin in intelliJ.

As a setting, I tried to make re-build when any change in code happens and press ctrl+s.

1. I check `Build project automatically`

[image]

2. I check `Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running`

[image]

3. I check `Any changes`

[image]

In case of `Registry..` I don't have `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` since mine is newer version than that.

Even though I set all, I run project in localhost:8080 and change template and save, page has nothing changed.

So I need to reload it again,,

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project? What version of IDE do you use?